# AngularJS: Access elements of inner array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

This is a simple html code and it is working fine. Now I have an AngularJS array and I can access and bind variables like `$scope.ID` or `$scope.text` which is working fine. 
But how can I bind values, to `$scope.articles` array. with relevant values.

**For example** 
 
If i change the value of f0, (just example it is not working) `$scope.articles.[0].betrag_gnetto` value should change 
If i change the value of f1, (just example it is not working) `$scope.articles.[1].betrag_netto` value should change

**HTML Code** (I have created these field through ng-repear loop)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="betrag_netto0" id="f0"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="betrag_netto1" id="f1">
<span ng-bind="betrag_netto0"></span>
<span ng-bind="betrag_netto1"></span>
```

**AngularJS Array looks like**

```
{  
   "isInternalInvoice":1,
      "name":"Rechnung",
      "ID":"5cd45e86",
      "text":null,
      "countArticles":2,
      "articles":[  
         {  
            "ID":"130.123",
            "betrag_netto":"123987"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"131.123",
            "betrag_netto":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: You access array elements without a leading period: `$scope.articles[0].betrag_gnetto`

Comment: no it is just an example! i cant access it through like this

Comment: I think you need to bind it to your model: `ng-model="articles[0].betrag_gnetto"`

Comment: is this right way to access values like...  scope.articles[0].betrag_netto ?? :

Comment: You can use nested `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create input fields corresponding to the objects present in the articles array using `ng-repeat` and this will make it two way binding.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
        "isInternalInvoice": 1,
        "name": "Rechnung",
        "ID": "5cd45e86",
        "text": null,
        "countArticles": 2,
        "articles": [{
            "ID": "130.123",
            "betrag_netto": "123987"
        }, {
            "ID": "131.123",
            "betrag_netto": "1"
        }]
    };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="article in obj.articles">
            <input type="text" ng-model="article.betrag_netto" id="f{{$index}}"> <span ng-bind="article.betrag_netto"></span> </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: omg, Thank you so much. I spend my previous whole day on it :) good luck in future :)

Answer (score 0):

try `$scope.articles[0].betrag_gnetto`

It works